# Squid won’t store my image

Tags: squid

After spending hours configuring squid 3.2.5, I only get TCP_MISS. To narrow the problem, I will focus on one PNG file that I want cached, but note that I get TCP_MISS for every single request, not only PNG files. The PNG file is accessible at [this address](http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/epo.png). Refreshing doesn’t help.

When I try to load it via squid, I get this line in access.log:

> 1357671721.566    127 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 618 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/epo.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22
>   image/png

And those in cache.log:

```
2013/01/08 20:02:59.768 kid1| client_side.cc(2298) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client local=127.0.0.1:3303 remote=127.0.0.1:42816 FD 19 flags=1
2013/01/08 20:02:59.769 kid1| client_side.cc(2299) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client REQUEST:
---------
GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/epo.png HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: flags.tatoeba.org
Connection: Close
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive


----------
2013/01/08 20:02:59.856 kid1| http.cc(2221) httpStart: httpStart: "GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/epo.png"
2013/01/08 20:02:59.856 kid1| http.cc(2177) sendRequest: HTTP Server local=192.168.1.13:56866 remote=86.65.39.22:80 FD 22 flags=1
2013/01/08 20:02:59.856 kid1| http.cc(2178) sendRequest: HTTP Server REQUEST:
---------
GET /img/flags/epo.png HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: flags.tatoeba.org
Via: 1.1 nomada (squid/3.2.5)
Cache-Control: max-age=15600540
Connection: keep-alive


----------
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| ctx: enter level  0: 'http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/epo.png'
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| http.cc(689) processReplyHeader: processReplyHeader: key 'EA06B401749A4C13ED95E8B5788A3010'
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| http.cc(732) processReplyHeader: HTTP Server local=192.168.1.13:56866 remote=86.65.39.22:80 FD 22 flags=1
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| http.cc(733) processReplyHeader: HTTP Server REPLY:
---------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 Jan 2013 19:03:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 219
Vary: User-Agent
Expires: Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, no-transform
Content-Type: image/png
Via: 1.1 tatoeba.fsffrance.org
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive

�PNG


----------
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| ctx: exit level  0
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| ctx: enter level  0: 'http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/epo.png'
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| http.cc(910) haveParsedReplyHeaders: haveParsedReplyHeaders: HTTP CODE: 200
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| http.cc(640) httpMakeVaryMark: httpMakeVaryMark: user-agent="Wget%2F1.14%20(linux-gnu)"
2013/01/08 20:02:59.898 kid1| ctx: exit level  0
2013/01/08 20:02:59.899 kid1| client_side.cc(1362) sendStartOfMessage: HTTP Client local=127.0.0.1:3303 remote=127.0.0.1:42816 FD 19 flags=1
2013/01/08 20:02:59.899 kid1| client_side.cc(1363) sendStartOfMessage: HTTP Client REPLY:
---------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 Jan 2013 19:03:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 219
Vary: User-Agent
Expires: Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, no-transform
Content-Type: image/png
X-Cache: MISS from nomada
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from nomada:3303
Via: 1.1 tatoeba.fsffrance.org, 1.1 nomada (squid/3.2.5)
Connection: keep-alive


----------
2013/01/08 20:02:59.899 kid1| http.cc(1044) persistentConnStatus: local=192.168.1.13:56866 remote=86.65.39.22:80 FD 22 flags=1 eof=0
```

My config file looks a lot like the default one, except for a couple changes:

```
cache_effective_user squid
cache_effective_group squid
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 901     # SWAT
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
debug_options ALL,1 11,3 31,3 65,3
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3303
cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 600 16 256
cache_mem 256 MB
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|bmp)$ 260000 90% 260009 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

My cache directory belongs to squid:squid, so no problem on that side either. And I am stumped for an answer.

Here is a chunk of my access.log:

```
1357671487.203    212 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 8263 GET http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/mwKa-gjx14k/mqdefault.jpg - HIER_DIRECT/74.125.230.238 image/jpeg
1357671487.235    134 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 10762 GET http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/O0bftzEOt9c/mqdefault.jpg - HIER_DIRECT/74.125.230.224 image/jpeg
1357671487.296    253 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 7415 GET http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/GPUnq0JSqRk/mqdefault.jpg - HIER_DIRECT/74.125.230.224 image/jpeg
1357671488.188    474 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 294 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - HIER_DIRECT/69.59.197.21 application/json
1357671505.309    255 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 533 GET http://s.youtube.com/s? - HIER_DIRECT/74.125.230.224 text/html
1357671516.404      0 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/503 6350 GET http://s.youtube.com/s? - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1357671533.221      0 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/503 4106 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1357671582.022    481 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 439 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - HIER_DIRECT/69.59.197.21 application/json
1357671597.029   1543 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 9700 GET http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/673940 - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/html
1357671597.166     47 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1426 GET http://tatoeba.org/js/sentences.random.js? - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 application/javascript
1357671597.205     86 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 2174 GET http://tatoeba.org/js/sentences_lists.menu.js? - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 application/javascript
1357671597.254    136 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1522 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/sentences/show.css? - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.254    136 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1324 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/elements/furigana.css - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.254     48 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1809 GET http://tatoeba.org/favicon.ico - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/x-icon
1357671597.258    137 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1150 GET http://js.tatoeba.org/js/furigana.js - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 application/javascript
1357671597.258    139 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1339 GET http://js.tatoeba.org/js/generic_functions.js? - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 application/javascript
1357671597.258     91 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 2471 GET http://js.tatoeba.org/js/autocompletion.js - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 application/javascript
1357671597.295    179 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 3232 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/layouts/default.css - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.332     39 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1234 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/elements/navigation.css - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.339     43 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1809 GET http://tatoeba.org/favicon.ico - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/x-icon
1357671597.342     49 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1774 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/elements/sentences_group.css - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.377     82 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1032 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/elements/logs_colors.css - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.384     90 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1014 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/elements/comment.css - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.384     89 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1124 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/elements/autocompletion.css - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.384     89 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1023 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/css/elements/logs_annexe.css - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 text/css
1357671597.410    292 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 21703 GET http://js.tatoeba.org/js/jquery-mini.js - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 application/javascript
1357671597.794    131 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1284 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/valid_16x16.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.795    133 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 595 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/arrow_down.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.800    137 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1256 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/add_to_list.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.801    137 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 618 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/epo.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.846     50 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1180 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/direct_translation.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.846     51 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 3008 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/loading.gif - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/gif
1357671597.846     45 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1539 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/eng.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.847     45 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 532 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/nld.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.860    197 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1072 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/loading-small.gif - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/gif
1357671597.887    224 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 16497 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/TatoebaProjectBeta.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.892     45 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1031 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/indirect_translation.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.892     45 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 520 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/ita.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.892     45 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 525 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/deu.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.892     44 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 718 GET http://flags.tatoeba.org/img/flags/jpn.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.908     47 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 541 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/img/bg_main.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.930     43 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 694 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/img/search_bar_body.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.933     39 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 584 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/img/module_background.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.935     42 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1572 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/img/search_bar_right.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.936     43 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1574 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/img/search_bar_left.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.936     42 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1378 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/img/title.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
1357671597.954     45 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1026 GET http://css.tatoeba.org/img/audio_unavailable.png - HIER_DIRECT/86.65.39.22 image/png
```

Answer (score 3):

The upstream webserver is returning an expiry time in the past, which will cause Squid to immediately consider the object stale.

```
Expires: Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT
```

That looks like a hardcoded timestamp, you probably want the webserver to return a relative expiry timestamp (e.g. now plus 1 month).

Comment: yep, I saw that, and I added `override-expire` on my config line

Comment: `refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|bmp)$ 260000 90% 260009 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private`

Answer (score 1):

If you found this answer because Squid is not caching objects that you expect it to, try setting `debug_options = ALL,2` in `/etc/squid3/squid.conf`.

Look out for lines like this after the response headers are logged:

```
store.cc(1003) checkCachable: StoreEntry::checkCachable: NO: too big
```

This can be caused by `maximum_object_size` being set too low (the default is 4 MB) or by the [Squid bug described here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/squid/msg69855.html) (also [filed in Ubuntu launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid3/+bug/1459638)) which causes `maximum_object_size` to be ignored if it occurs after `cache_dir` in `squid.conf`, which it does in the standard distributed configuration file template.

```
store.cc(994) checkCachable: StoreEntry::checkCachable: NO: not cachable
```

Non-caching can also be caused by the remote server trying to disable client or proxy caching, by sending various headers along with the reply (as described in the [HTTP standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.1.3)), for example:

- `Expires` with a date in the past (forcing immediate expiry), or
- `Cache-control: no-cache` or `Cache-control: private`.

The client (e.g. a web browser) can also explicitly disable caching. For example, if you use the Reload or force-reload option, which depends on the browser, but conventionally:

- pressing the F5 or shift-F5 key, or
- clicking on the Reload button with or without the Shift key pressed.

Then the browser will explicitly disable caching, probably using one of the following mechanisms (see also [RFC 2616 section 14.9.4](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4)):

> Sometimes a user agent might want or need to insist that a cache revalidate its cache entry with the origin server (and not just with the next cache along the path to the origin server), or to reload its cache entry from the origin server. End-to-end revalidation might be necessary if either the cache or the origin server has overestimated the expiration time of the cached response. End-to-end reload may be necessary if the cache entry has become corrupted for some reason.
>
> The client can specify these three kinds of action using Cache- Control request directives: ...
>
> The request includes a "no-cache" cache-control directive or, for compatibility with HTTP/1.0 clients, "Pragma: no-cache".

If you want to ensure that the client is not doing something to deliberately disable caching, you can test it by downloading the same file with `wget`, using your Squid/HTTP proxy:

```
http_proxy=http://yourproxy:3128 wget -O /dev/null http://yourhost/yourfile
```

And check in the Squid logs to see what happened to the request, and whether or not Squid decided to cache the response, and why (see above).